# Eigenvectors of a random non-Hermitian symmetric tridiagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Are eigenvectors of a random non-Hermitian symmetric tridiagonal Matrix (with complex components) [localized](http://www.google.com/#q=localized+eigenvectors)?

[image]

Comment: Note that your problem is exactly solvable in terms of orthogonal polynomials w.r.t. a random measure; your hamiltonian is then the [Jacobi matrix](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~alexb/rm/Jacobi.pdf) for those polynomials. (Specifically, the eigenvalues will be the zeros of the $n$th polynomial, and the $i$th entry will be the $i$th polynomial evaluated at the eigenvalue.) However, for your question to have an answer, you need to make it very clear and very precise what you mean by "random" in this situation. What distribution are the $t_i$'s drawn from?

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

Comment: In my question, t_n=C_n+i C'_n where C_n=A*exp(-B*x_n) and C'_n=A'*x_n*exp(-B*x_n) where x_n are uncorrelated random numbers with exponential distribution such that C_n be uncorrelated random numbers with uniform distribution in the interval [t_0*(1-D),t_0*(1+D)]